# Connect to SFTP using Centos Linux VM

Tags: centos, sftp

I have Centos running a Linux VM on a Windows machine.  I'm not able to connect to the VM using WinSCP with sftp on port 22 or ftp on port 21.  I have

```
Subsystem  sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. I've executed

```
/etc/init.d/sshd start
```

I have openssh-server installed in /usr/libexec/openssh.  When I try to connect using WinSCP the message I get says "The server rejected SFTP connection, but it listens for FTP connections."  Then when I switch to port 21 and try to connect the message says "Disconnected from server
Connection failed."  I have the vm running and the ip address I'm trying to connect to matches the inet address I get when I run ifconfig

Comment: you need to add some more detail about networking used between host and guest. For example, if using a NAT'ed interface, you'll have to set some port redirection in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Try `ps aux | grep sshd` on the remote server. This will tell you whether the SSH daemon is started.

If not, you have to look at the log to see why it did not start and correct the configuration file.

If yes, you have to figure out on which port is is listening `netstat -ntapl` and use it in WinSCP.

If it is still not working even by using the right port, you may have an issue with your credentials.

Comment: I see it running when executing ps aux | grep sshd executing the next command I see sshd on 127.0.0.1:25, I switched to port 25 in WinSCP and it says "Server unexpectedly closed network connection"

Comment: You need to listen on 0.0.0.0 (ListenAdress in your sshd config file).

Comment: In my sshd_config file I uncommented #ListenAddress 0.0.0.0 and was still unable to connect on ports 21, 22, and 25.  I then uncommented #Port 22 two lines above the listen address and was unable to connect on port 22 or any ports in WinSCP.  It says "The server rejected SFTP connection, but it listens for FTP connections." when I try to connect on port 22, "Server unexpectedly closed network connection when I try to connect on port 25", and "Disconnected from server" on port 21.  Running netstat -ntapl now that I've uncommented shows: tcp   0   0 0.0.0.0:22

Comment: There is another #ListenAddress line beneath the ListenAddress I uncommented that says #ListenAddress ::

Comment: Actually it says in the file that the commented values are the default values

Comment: If netstat shows the address 0.0.0.0:22 then you should be able to connect. If not, you either changed firewall rules so that port 22 in unreachable: you have to change that back. Or your credentials are wrong.